# How would I parse multiple or more objects via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

like so

````
► add language identifier to highlight code

```python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
````

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links (use https whenever possible)
https://example.com
[example](https://example.com)
[example](https://example.com)

Comment: You are suppose to post a _minimal working code snippet_ within the question, reproducing the issue diescribed.

Comment: I'm surprised you get *anything* because `obj.[0]FFN` is a syntax error.

Comment: obj is what the JSON is saved as, 0 is the block and FFN is the object inside the 0 index block.. I don't see anything wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Pointy there are multiple syntax errors in your code (when accessing the `obj` array).

But the reason it wouldn't work even after you fix these syntax errors is that the result of your API call is a string and you need to parse it using `JSON.parse()`.

```js
$.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielhoset27/test1/master/C2RReleaseData.json', function(obj) {
  // Parse the received json
  const result = JSON.parse(obj);
  // Fix the syntax errors
  document.writeln(result[0].FFN + " : " + result[0].AvailableBuild);
  // Add a line break
  document.write('<br />')
  // Fix the syntax errors again
  document.writeln(result[1].FFN + " : " + result[1].AvailableBuild);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also consider using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is your targeted browsers support it.

```js
const appendItem = item => document.body.innerHTML += `<p>${item.FFN} : ${item.AvailableBuild}</p>`;

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielhoset27/test1/master/C2RReleaseData.json').then(response => {
  response.json().then(result => {
    appendItem(result[0]);
    appendItem(result[1]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url  = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielhoset27/test1/master/C2RReleaseData.json';
        $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
            for(var i in data){
                console.log(data[i].FFN + " : " + data[i].AvailableBuild)
            }
        });
    });
```